# finding the middle number in C

Tags: c, syntax

THIS IS HOMEWORK. thought i'd let you know. if you could point me in the direction that would help me discover why this error is happening, i'd appreciate it.
http://pastebin.com/hDUpfrsu is my current code (included below). why does it return ONE when i enter (in this order) `5, 6, 7` or other sequences?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <simpio.h>
#include <genlib.h>

/* finds the minimum among three integers using minimal amount of relational operations */

int main()
{
    int myNumbers[2];
    bool lowest;
    printf("Enter the first integer...\t");
    myNumbers[0] = GetInteger();
    printf("Enter the second integer...\t");
    myNumbers[1] = GetInteger();
    printf("Enter the third integer...\t");
    myNumbers[2] = GetInteger();

    if (myNumbers[0] < myNumbers[1] && myNumbers[0] < myNumbers[2])
    {
       lowest = myNumbers[0];
    }

    if (myNumbers[0] > myNumbers[1] && myNumbers[1] < myNumbers[2])
    {
       lowest = myNumbers[1];
    }

    if (myNumbers[0] > myNumbers[2] && myNumbers[1] > myNumbers[2])
    {
       lowest = myNumbers[2];
    }

    printf("\n%d", lowest);
    getchar();
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your comment say "finds the minimum among three integers using minimal amount of relational operations" but the operations are not really minimal as implemented.

Comment: how would i fix that do you think?

Comment: You can fix it by nesting your if statements.  For instance the first test can be myNumbers[0] < myNumbers[1].  In the if branch you further test whether myNumbers[0] < myNumbers[2].  etc.  This will also fix the logic error you have where lowest is not properly set if there is a tie for lowest place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues:

- lowest is defined as a `bool`, it should be an `int` with how you are using it
- `myNumbers[2]` is an array of size 2, it can only hold 2 numbers. Change the size declaration to 3.
- Consider what would happen if two or more of the values were equal...

Comment: `int myNumbers[2]` is an array of size 2, so the valid indices are `myNumbers[0]` and `myNumbers[1]`. In order to use `myNumbers[2]` you need to declare the array to be of size 3 (eg. `int myNumbers[3]`).

Comment: based on other comments, it seems as though you are misunderstanding array sizes. Defining a size of array[n] makes it have n 'slots', and because it is zero indexed the valid indices are 0..n-1.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
bool lowest;
```

by

```
int lowest;
```

since you want to store an integer number in 'lowest', not a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

`lowest` is a `bool`. Shouldn't it be something larger?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that, as many others have pointed out, you're using *lowest* as a **boolean** type, instead of a number type, such as **int**, which would be in harmony with the rest of your program.

```
bool lowest;
```

Boolean types, as expected, can hold basically two states: **true** and **false**. For historical reasons (i.e., mainly because of the **C** inheritance), boolean values have been associated with integer numbers, for which 0 meant false and any other value meant true.

That's why the Boolean type is still compatible with integers (that's a way of saying this), and when you assign it to a zero, then it holds false. If you assign to it any other int value, it will hold true. This is happening in lines such as this one:

```
lowest = myNumbers[0];
```

Finally, when you execute:

```
printf("\n%d", lowest);
```

The inverse process takes place, and **true** is converted to **int** (since you specified *%d* in the *printf* format string), and **true** is converted to 1, which is the default integer value for true in the **bool** type when its integer value: `(int) true` (in your program: `(int) lowest`) is asked.

As you can imagine, more than 90% of times the input integer values are going to be different from zero, that's why you are obtaining 1, no matter the input.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to other's answers.

You have:

```
int myNumbers[2];
...
myNumbers[2] = GetInteger();
```

this is incorrect. `myNumbers` is an array of 2 elements and valid array indices are `0` and `1`. Since you want to store `3` elements in the array change its size to `3`.

Comment: myNumbers[2] holds myNumbersp[0-2] actually so three values

Comment: When you declare an array in C, the number in the brackets represents the number of elements, not the last index.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Your array isn't big enough. When you declare an array, the index isn't the maximum index of the array, but the number of elements, which is the maximum index + 1.

Comment: The number given in the declaration of the array is the number of elements, not the last index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Ternary Operator ( ? :)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)**  To find lowest number or highest b/w three numbers with **minimum number of relational operators(As you said)**.

```
int low, lowest;
low = (number[0] < number[1]) ? number[0] : number[1];
lowest =(low < number[2]) ? low : number[2];
printf("%d",lowest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed about the obvious flaws in the program (viz size of array, data type of the result). 
Here is a bit which will make you understand the indexing of arrays, specifically w[hy they start from zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509129/why-do-arrays-start-from-zero)?

PS: I like the top rated answer but i advise you to read the entire post.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered so I will post a solution that is much simpler:

```
int lowest = myNumbers[0];
if (myNumbers[1] < lowest)
{
    lowest = myNumbers[1];
}
if (myNumbers[2] < lowest)
{
    lowest = myNumbers[2];
}
printf("lowest value is: %d\n", lowest);
```

You only need that many conditions!